# How do i get git-media to track/sync deletes back to my S3 bucket?

Tags: git, amazon-s3, git-media

I'm using [git-media](https://github.com/alebedev/git-media) to manage large video files in a git repo.

Desired Behaviour - When i want to delete a video from a project, i want that delete to be reflected in my S3 bucket.

Current Behaviour - I can only add new files and sync changes to existing. Deleted local video files leave a file on the S3 bucket.

Over time i'm worried this is going to result in a lot of waste? Is this by design or should i be able to have git-media reflect my deletes?

Any insight/experiences would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I could delete this but i think its better to admit your face palm moments and embrace them. Hagen (a git-media) fork maintainer kindly took to the time to remind me how 'git' works :

If you would delete a file in a git repo it will stay in the history and you will be able to restore it by checking out a particular commit. This implies for git-media that every file you added at one time to its storage has to stay there forever, otherwise yoy cannot perform the checkout in git.

If you are looking for a different behaviour you should consider that you maybe do not need git for storing your data.

Bottom line - You never really delete anything in git once its added so you can't expect S3 to delete files you add without breaking your ability to roll back to a previous commit where it exists again.